# Python Flask and MongoDB custom search

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am using flask, react on the frontend (which works and sends the query to the backend), and doing this all for the first time. The end goal here is to have the user entered query broken down so that it finds what the user wants and returns that value from the MongoDB document. So, for example, if a user wants to know the weight of a bag the code searches by `checkedBagWeight` and it will go into the document where the airline matches and return the value for `checkedBagWeight` My issue is no matter what I do I can never get it to return the data t always says nothing is found

How it works:
User query: United Airlines checked bag weight
query sent to backend
backend deconstructs the query
Checks for the following:

1. Airline Name
2. Search item (bag, baggage, etc.) - for now we're working with baggage
3. Specific search item (checked bag, carry-on bag, etc.)
4. If airline name is in the search query sent the DB named AirlineInfo
5. Based on search item enter that collection (for now it's just BaggageInfo)
6. Search through the collection for the airline name United Airlines (use the airlines dictionary so if a user enters United it searches with Unitec Airlines)
7. Search that document in the collection that matches the airline for the specific information the query wants (if user says United checked bag weight it returns that item in the docment)

Example Document:

```
_id: 651d7a78cf3af11191af0e7a
airlineName: "United Airlines"
carryOnBagSize: "22 x 14 x 9"
checkedBagSize: "62 linear inches (L + W + H)"
checkedBagWeight: "50 lbs"
policy: "Placeholder text"
```

So as of now when I enter a search query here is what my backend returns to me:

```
Query received: United Airlines checked bag weight
Query: {'airlineName': 'United Airlines', 'checkedBagWeight': {'$exists': True, '$ne': None}}
Received search query: United Airlines checked bag weight
Response: No baggage information found.
```

Here are my two code files:

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from search import handle_search

load_dotenv()

uri = os.getenv('MONGO_URI')
client = MongoClient(uri)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
 
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Connected to MongoDB!")
except ConnectionFailure as e:
    print("Failed to connect to MongoDB because:", e)

db = client.AirlineInfo

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Pong!'})

@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    data = request.json
    search_query = data.get('query')

    print('Data:', data)
    print('Search Query:', search_query)
    response = handle_search(search_query, db)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Search.py:

```
# search.py
from flask import jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Define search parameters
search_params = {
    "checked": "checkedBagWeight",
    "carry-on": "carryOn",
    "weight": "checkedBagWeight",
}

# Define airline mappings
airlines = {
    "united": "United Airlines",
}

def handle_search(query, db):
    query_words = query.lower().split()

    response_message = "No relevant information found."

    baggage_info_collection = db.AirlineInfo.BaggageInfo

    # Extract airline name from the query
    airline_name = None
    for word in query_words:
        if word in airlines:
            airline_name = airlines[word]
            break

    search_param = None
    for word in query_words:
        if word in search_params:
            search_param = search_params[word]
            break

    if airline_name and search_param:
        result = search_baggage_info(airline_name, search_param, baggage_info_collection)
        if result:
            response_message = result

    print("Received search query:", query)
    print("Response:", response_message)

    return jsonify({'message': response_message})

def search_baggage_info(airline_name, search_param, baggage_info_collection):
    try:
        query = {
            "airlineName": airline_name,
            search_param: {"$exists": True, "$ne": None}
        }
        print("Query:", query)
        result = baggage_info_collection.find_one(query)

        if result and search_param in result:
            return result[search_param]

        return "No baggage information found."
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred in search_baggage_info: {str(e)}")
        return "Error occurred while searching for baggage information."
```

I've tried different ways to structure the query and I am just lost I know it's in the right collection and DB I just don't know why it won't return the value for the `search_param` which is set to be the exact name of how it is in my mongo DB document.

Comment: In your `server.py`, you've named your database `AirlineInfo`, but in `search.py`, you're accessing a collection named `BaggageInfo` through `db.AirlineInfo.BaggageInfo`: shouldn't the db name match?

Comment: In addition to @VonC comment above, the search_params dictionary has ```"carry-on": "carryOn"```, but the example doc has ```"carryOnBagSize"```. As well, the search params is using ```"checkedBagWeight"``` twice, does ```"checked": "checkedBagWeight"```, need to be ```"checked": "checkedBagSize"```. Do you need to remediate all these inconsistencies first?

Comment: I know there are a lot of inconsistencies and they need to be fixed but shouldn't something be returned to me since at least one thing matches?
```Query received: United Airlines Checked Bag Weight
Query: {'airlineName': 'United Airlines', 'checkedBagWeight': {'$exists': True, '$ne': None}}
Received search query: United Airlines Checked Bag Weight
Response: No baggage information found.```
the Query is what it should be searching by and just return the value associated with that, so it goes into the collection for United Airlines and match `checkedBagWeight`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MongoDB query issue, based on the query log you shared, the constructed query seems to be in the correct format. The query `{'airlineName': 'United Airlines', 'checkedBagWeight': {'$exists': True, '$ne': None}}` should indeed look for a document where the `airlineName` is "`United Airlines`" and where the `checkedBagWeight` field exists and is not null.

Make sure first that you are querying the correct [collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-collection).
In your code, you are trying to access the collection via `db.AirlineInfo.BaggageInfo`, but based on the structure you provided it seems like it should just be `db.BaggageInfo` (assuming `BaggageInfo` is the name of your collection).

And check that the [field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-field) names `airlineName` and `checkedBagWeight` match exactly with the field names in your MongoDB documents, including the case (upper/lower).

Also double-check there are proper [indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/) on the `airlineName` and `checkedBagWeight` fields in your MongoDB collection to improve query performance.

For testing:

- Try [executing the query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/tutorial/query-documents/) manually using a MongoDB client or shell to make sure the query indeed returns the expected result.
  The query based on the information provided should be:

  ```js
  db.BaggageInfo.find({'airlineName': 'United Airlines', 'checkedBagWeight': {'$exists': True, '$ne': None}})
  ```
- Temporarily modify your code to execute a simplified query to see if it returns the expected result. For example:

  ```py
  result = baggage_info_collection.find_one({"airlineName": "United Airlines"})
  ```

---

That being said, [djmonki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11543023/djmonki)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77318420/python-flask-and-mongodb-custom-search?noredirect=1#comment136345609_77318420) remains valid: the discrepancy in field names would certainly cause the queries to not match any documents, resulting in the message "`No baggage information found.`"

- The `search_params` dictionary has `"carry-on": "carryOn"`, but the field in the MongoDB document is `carryOnBagSize`. That discrepancy will cause the query to fail when searching for carry-on bag information. It should be corrected to `"carry-on": "carryOnBagSize"` in the `search_params` dictionary.
- The `search_params` dictionary maps `"checked": "checkedBagWeight"` and `"weight": "checkedBagWeight"`. If the intention is to map a query for checked bag size, then indeed `"checked": "checkedBagSize"` should be the correct mapping, assuming `checkedBagSize` is the correct field name in the MongoDB document.

The corrected `search_params` dictionary based on the observations would be:

```py
search_params = {
    "checked": "checkedBagSize",
    "carry-on": "carryOnBagSize",
    "weight": "checkedBagWeight",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use NLP to extract information from given query statement . he is example code that will help you to use NLP

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

def get_question_type(text):
  tokens = word_tokenize(text)
  tagged_tokens = pos_tag(tokens)
  question_type = None

  for token, tag in tagged_tokens:
    if tag == "NN" or tag == "NNP":
      question_type = "airline"
      break
    elif tag == "VB" or tag == "VBD":
      question_type = "action"
      break
    elif tag == "JJ" or tag == "JJR" or tag == "JJS":
      question_type = "adjective"
      break
    elif tag == "WRB":
      question_type = "adverb"
      break
    elif token == "weight":
      question_type = "weight"

  return question_type

def get_airline_name(text):
  tokens = word_tokenize(text)
  for token in tokens:
    if token.isalpha() and len(token) > 2:
      return token

def get_weight(text):
  tokens = word_tokenize(text)
  for token in tokens:
    if token.isdigit():
      return token

def main():
  text = "I flew United Airlines from San Francisco to Los Angeles. What is the baggage allowance for my flight?"
  question_type = get_question_type(text)
  airline_name = get_airline_name(text)
  weight = get_weight(text)

  if question_type == "weight":
    if airline_name == "United Airlines":
      print("The baggage allowance for United Airlines is 50 pounds per passenger.")
    else:
      print("The baggage allowance for {} is {} pounds per passenger.".format(airline_name, weight))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```